# How to Iterate over droplists using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

So basically, I have a list of droplists that I need to interact with.

[image]

I know how to interact with the first droplist.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.headless = False



driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options = options) 
driver.set_window_size(1920,1080)


driver.get("https://www.compraensanjuan.com")
time.sleep(3)


link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Mi cuenta")
link.click()
time.sleep(3)

email = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
email.send_keys("yourmail")


password = driver.find_element_by_name("clave")
password.send_keys("Yourpassword")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(3)

drp = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("acciones"))

drp.select_by_visible_text("Actualizar") 

driver.back()
```

But how do I repeat the same action for all the following droplists??

Comment: Which action? And by `all the following droplists` do you refer to all `<select>` elements from page?

Comment: The action is to click on the droplist, and then click on update ("Actualizar"). Then repeat on all the select elements.

Comment: First of all try to find an common xpath which identify all your needed `select` elements. And with `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("commonxpath");` get all `select` into an array and iterate that array and perform your actions on them

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get a list of the options, and then iterate over them. Something like:

```py
options = driver.find_element_by_name('DropdownElement')
options = options.text.split('\n')

for opt in options:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='DropdownElement']/option[text()='"+opt+"']").click()
```

Comment: I think you want to use `..._elements_...` instead of `..._element_...`